# How To View Process Instead Of Splash Screen During Boot By Pressing A Key?

Tags: boot, 16.04, keyboard

I am on ubuntu 16.04, and few days back i was having slow startup problem and on startup I accidentally pressed a key on keyboard and instead of ubuntu logo showing all background process that are happening during startup were started to show, now I do not remember which key it was.

Can Someone Guide Me How to view the background process during startup, i know the other solution of updating the grib file and removing "quite splash" . I want to know the key which when press shows the processes that start on boot?

Answer (score 3):

To disable the splash screen and display the boot messages in Ubuntu press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

The animated splash screen is controlled by a package called ***Plymouth*** which you can google to find more options.